# augeas not recognizing file in tmp directory

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppet, rhel, augeas

I am having issue with Augeas on my redhat ec2. I recently started using this API, so far used only for changes in `/etc/` directory.

Here is OS that I used.

```
OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

what I have found recently is augtool is not recognizing any files other than files in /etc/ and /boot/.

for example:`augtool> print /files/tmp/sample/test.cfg` will not give any result.

test.cfg

```
[Credentials]
Keys = True
```

For testing purposes I moved this file from /tmp/ to /etc/httpd/conf.d/, but augeas still not printing contents of it. Where are it print config tree of my apache config file.

I am trying to put them in puppet, here is my code:

```
augeas {"changeTest" :
  context => "/files/tmp/sample/test.cfg",
  changes => "set Credentials/Keys False"
}
```

This is what I saw in my puppet debug:

```
Debug: Augeas[changeTest](provider=augeas): sending command 'set' with params ["/files/tmp/sample/test.cfg/Credentials/Keys", "False"]
Debug: Augeas[changeTest](provider=augeas): Skipping because no files were changed
```

What I am doing wring here?

Answer (score 1):

Augeas doesn't "recognize" files, or knows the standard paths of these files. /tmp is not a standard location for any configuration file, so augeas cannot know what to do.

In Puppet, you can tell augeas which lens (I.e. parser) to use for a given file:

```
augeas {"changeTest" :
  incl => "/tmp/sample/test.cfg",
  lens => "Httpd.lns",
  changes => "set Credentials/Keys False",
}
```

Comment: For some examples and pitfalls, see https://inftec.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TEC/Puppet#Puppet-Augeas

Comment: It'd be nice if this Atlassian page mentioned augeasproviders, too.